# Difference between "<> ANY(…)" and "NOT = ANY(…)"?

Tags: sql-standard, operator

Could you please explain the difference between these two operators?

sID != smth and not sID = smth.

At a first glance they seem perfectly equal. But they give different results.

[image: example]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
NOT sid = ANY (SELECT ...)
```

is equivalent to:

```
sid <> ALL (SELECT ...)
```

So, your two conditions are not the same.

---

`ALL` and `ANY` operators are hard for me (and many people) to use. I think that's how many prefer to use `IN`, `NOT IN`, `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` which result in more self-explanatory code.

If you do want to work with them, think that `sid = ANY (SELECT ...)` means "check if `sid` is equal to any (some) of the `(select...)` values".

Then the `NOT sid = ANY (SELECT ...)` is the opposite of that. But the opposite of "equal to any of them" is "different to all of them" (and not "different to some of them").

Comment: Perhaps highlighting the difference in English between "sid is not equal to any <...>" and "there is any <...> that sid is not equal to" helps too.

Answer (score 3):

This is what the SQL Standard has to say about `ANY`

> <quantified comparison predicate> ::=
>         <row value constructor> <comp op> <quantifier> <table subquery>
>
> <quantifier> ::= <all> | <some>
>
> <all> ::= ALL
>
> <some> ::= SOME | ANY
>
> General Rules
>
> 1) Let R be the result of the <row value constructor> and let T
>   be
>       the result of the <table subquery>.
>
> 2) The result of "R <comp op> <quantifier> T" is derived
>   by the
>       application of the implied <comparison predicate> "R <comp op>
>       RT" to every row RT in T:
>
> Case:
>
> a) If T is empty or if the implied <comparison predicate> is
>         true for every row RT in T, then "R <comp op> <all> T" is
>         true.
>
> b) If the implied <comparison predicate> is false for at least
>         one row RT in T, then "R <comp op> <all> T" is false.
>
> c) **If the implied <comparison predicate> is true for at least
>         one row RT in T, then "R <comp op> <some> T" is true.**
>
> d) **If T is empty or if the implied <comparison predicate> is
>         false for every row RT in T, then "R <comp op> <some> T" is
>         false.**
>
> e) If "R <comp op> <quantifier> T" is neither true nor false,
>         then it is unknown.

Consider the case that sID = 1 and the sub query returns 1,2,3.

The result of the comparisons is

```
+---+-------+-------+
|   |   =   |  <>   |
+---+-------+-------+
| 1 | TRUE  | FALSE |
| 2 | FALSE | TRUE  |
| 3 | FALSE | TRUE  |
+---+-------+-------+
```

So `= ANY` returns true because it checks that there is at least one row `=1`.

```
TRUE OR FALSE OR FALSE = TRUE
```

Conversely `<> ANY` also returns true because it checks that there is at least one row `<> 1`.

```
FALSE OR TRUE OR TRUE = TRUE
```

Then you negate the  `<> ANY` so it becomes `false`.